# Locked out of phone

Tags: cell-phone

[image: ultra gsm modelo j8 android dual sim]

I've locked myself out of my phone don't remember screen lock pin could someone help with a solution that doesn't require me hard setting it.

Comment: Might be a good idea to put the make and model on your question, as well as the operating system

Answer (score 3):

There probably isn't a reliable solution to this problem.  The whole point of security locks on phones is to prevent unauthorized use.  If you've forgotten the unlock code (pattern, pin, password, whatever), you're "unauthorized" as far as the phone can tell.  This is Operating As Designed, and you'd need tools for hacking the phone to bypass it.

If you have photos, music, and such stored on a micro-SD, you may be able to eject the card and copy the contents from it (depending on your Android version -- some versions encrypt the card or store contents in a form that's only readable by the phone it was installed on).  Other than that, the only option I could suggest is your cell carrier's tech support, who will likely only be able/permitted to guide you through factory resetting the phone.

Comment: Older samsung devices (up to the S6 but maybe later...) can have the recovery partition replaced _without_ wiping data, so if the partition was not encrypted, data can still be retrieved, and the screen lock file can just be deleted. If it uses the fastboot bootloader mechanism however, then unlocking the bootloader to replace the recovery partition will factory reset the phone anyway, making it useless. This, again, is operating as designed. Just thought I'd comment on the off chance OP is running a custom recovery.